# IndexError: list index out of range in text file (Python)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have this bit of code that's inside a perpetual while loop, and whenever I try to get a random line from a text file, it occasionally throws an index error. Can anybody help me with this? I've already checked my text file and there are 452 lines inside. At first I thought it was some number error so I reduced the upper bound, but the error keeps occurring. The starred piece of code is what is causing the error.

```
        if len(bank)==445:
            bank = []

        randinte = random.randint(1,450)
        samecheck(randinte, bank, 450)

        text_file = open("text.txt", "r")
        **line = text_file.readlines()[randinte]**
        twitter.update_status(
            status=line)
        text_file.close()
        bank.append(randinte)
```

EDIT: Thank you for all the help! This is the code I ended up using and working. repopulate() is a method that populates bank from 1-451 sequentially.

```
        if len(bank)==5:
            bank = []
            repopulate()

        random.shuffle(bank)   
        text_file = open("text.txt", "r")
        lines = text_file.readlines()
        line = lines[bank.pop()]
        twitter.update_status(
            status=line)
        text_file.close()
```

Comment: Why not use `len()` of the `readlines()` result to pick a random number?

Comment: I'm not following, isn't `readlines()` the method to return the line in a text file?

Comment: I mean: `lines = text_file.readlines()` then `randinte = random.randint(len(lines))` and `line = lines[randinte]`. That way at least line 0 can be picked too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not clear without seeing your text file why you might be getting these index errors, but its best to avoid hard-coding things like lengths of files if possible anyway. Another option would be to use the `choice` method in the `random` module to just choose a random line returned from `readlines()`, as below:

```
    if len(bank)==445:
        bank = []

    text_file = open("text.txt", "r")
    lines = text_file.readlines()

    line = random.choice(lines) # choose a random line

    twitter.update_status(
        status=line)
    text_file.close()
```

Comment: I *think* the OP is storing `randinte` in `bank` to test for repeated choices first. So the specific line number is something the OP is storing here.

Comment: That said, in that case, read the file once and use `random.shuffle()` then `lines.pop()` each time you want a random line would be a better choice.

Comment: Right! If they are in fact doing that, then there's absolutely no reason to be reading in the same file over and over.. My assumption was that this was for a new text file each time.

Comment: Would it be possible to get the line # from this method? I would like to append it to `bank` until `len(bank) == 445`

edit: yes you are correct in your assumption, but I've read that it's good to close the file after each usage.

Comment: Do you need the line number for a particular reason? Why not just have a variable "count" that adds +1 each time a line is added until count == 445? That said, if you do actually want to grab the line number, do it with the `index` method: `linenumber = lines.index(line)`

Comment: Only to make sure that each sequence is random. IF I were to use the `shuffle()` and `pop()` method, would I create a list of integers from 1-450, call `shuffle()`, then `pop()`?

Comment: You could, or you could shuffle the list of lines from `readlines` itself.